# Get value from xml node without html decoding in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

```
DECLARE @P1 xml
SET @P1='<Root><Data>&lt;script&gt;function abc(){}&lt;script&gt;</Data></Root>'
SELECT @P1

SELECT @P1.value('(/Root/Data)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

The above code is giving the value as

```
<script>function abc(){}<script>
```

i.e html decoded.But how do I get the value without html decode. Is there any way to get the actual value inside the node element?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the element value without replacing the entity references using the query method, and then casting the XML text node to varchar:

```
SELECT CAST(@P1.query('(/Root/Data)[1]/text()') AS varchar(MAX));
```